# Is "Valence Electron Density" and "Electron Density" data of a molecule the same thing?

Tags: density-functional-theory, molecular-dynamics, physical-properties-of-materials, machine-learning, electron-density

I'm wondering specifically in the context of **calculating physical properties** from *valence-electron-density data* using  DFT, MD, and or ML (machine learning).

Comment: I guess one can calculate practically everything that can be calculated from the full electron density, since one can always pre-tabulate the frozen core densities of atoms, add them to the valence electron density, and do regular property calculations. The resulting density will be only slightly off from the exact full density, since core electron densities are highly transferable.

Comment: +1 to the question and also to the comment from @wzkchem5, which I think would be a good answer to the question: if "valence electron density" is just an approximation to the "full electron density" then the former *can* calculate most things that the latter can (except maybe something involving just the core electrons, for example the core ionization energy to remove an electron from the core).

Comment: @wzkchem5 can you suggest any sources where I/the community can read up on Electron Densities, their properties and their various types?

Comment: @PranoyRay I guess I don't have any material specially dedicated for electron densities at hand, but I think any quantum chemistry textbook, especially those published after year 2000 (the 20th century textbooks tend to focus mainly on wavefunctions), will have the things you want

Comment: possible duplicate: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/2482/what-can-we-learn-by-inspecting-charge-densities-calculated-with-dft

Comment: @PranoyRay your follow-up question to wzkchem5 about resources to learn about electron densities, needs to be asked in a separate question, not a comment. Did the answers to the thread given by wcw in the above comment, combined with the fact that the properties you can calculate with the valence electron densities are going to be pretty much the same as for the full electron density, help to answer your question? I am beginning to doubt that much more will get revealed here.

Comment: The question is closed pending clarification by the OP. It can be reopened if someone wishes to provide an answer or the OP addresses questions in the comments.